# Why my mesh object gets destroyed when I move it in edit mode?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, transforms, faces

I have a mesh object that behaves fine when I move it in object mode. But if I switch to *Edit Mode*, select all faces and move them just a bit, the mesh gets destroyed and some faces disappear.

What is wrong with this object? I have more human models like this one and most of them don't present such an issue.

Left is before, right is after:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable the [Auto-Merge](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/tools/tool_settings.html?highlight=auto%20merge#auto-merge) option. From the manual:

> When the Auto Merge option is enabled, as soon as a vertex moves closer to another one than the Threshold setting, they are automatically merged.

[image]

Comment: Yup, it works. Thank you :)